# If $x^2+3x+5=0$ and $ax^2+bx+c=0$ have a common root and $a,b,c\in \mathbb{N}$, find the minimum value of $a+b+c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, quadratics

If $x^2+3x+5=0$ and $ax^2+bx+c=0$ have a common root and $a,b,c\in \mathbb{N}$, find the minimum value of $a+b+c$

Using the condition for common root, $$(3c-5b)(b-3a)=(c-5a)^2$$
$$3bc-9ac-5b^2+15ab=c^2+25a^2-10ac$$
$$25a^2+5b^2+c^2=15ab+3bc+ac$$
There is pattern in the equation. The coefficients of the middle terms and first terms of both sides are $(5\times 5,5)$ and $(5\times 3,3)$.

I tried to use Lagrange multipliers. But isnt there any simpler way to minimize $a+b+c$?

Comment: I guess the true problem should be with undetermined coefficients  instead of $3$ and $5$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

The roots of $x^2+3x+5$ are not real, and if $z\in \Bbb C$ is a root of a polynomial with real coefficients but $z$ is not real, then $\bar z$ is also a root of this polynimial.

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial $x^2+3x+5$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Hence, if $x^2+3x+5$ and $ax^2+bx+c$, with $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Q}$, have a common root, they must be proportional.  That is, $$ax^2+bx+c=a\left(x^2+3x+5\right)\,.$$

The problem would be more challenging if $x^2+3x+5$ is replaced by $x^2+3x+2$.

Answer (score 0):

See one root is complex so other os obviously its conjugate as $b^2-4ac<0$ so the equations have both roots in common and as $a,b,c$ have no common factor thus $min(a+b+c)=1+3+5=9$

Comment: From where did you get 1+3+5 ?

Comment: From the given equation